# Openai: `prompt` column/key is missing. Please make sure you name your columns/keys appropriately, then retry

Tags: python, openai-api, gpt-3

I want to run GPT-3 for text classification. As the first step, I prepare data using openai CLI. I got a csv file which looks like as follow:

[image]

I wrote following command for preparing the data:

```
openai tools fine_tunes.prepare_data -f "Path\\training_dataset.csv"
```

However, I got following error:

[image]

I am not sure about "name columns/keys appropriately". Is there any convention that I should follow? Any help would be really appreciated to fix the error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may convert your csv/tsv file to json, rename the header as prompt and completion.

Like this:
| prompt | completion |
| -------- | -------------- |
| text1    | result1        |
| text2    | result2        |

Comment: I do not understand you. Where do I write what you say?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing in your excel "Review Text" to "prompt" and "target" to "completion".
OR
Copy the `prompt`/`completion` the program says is missing and paste in the column header

Then try the command again.